# Deleting of an user is not preventing resource access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication to log in to my app and Firebase Storage to save some files.

The problem is that even I have defined such safety rules for storage:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

When I delete or disable a user from Authentication Firebase manual panel then this user still can add and remove files to/from our storage.

With above rules I wanted to prevent a user to read/write when he/she is not authenticated.

According to documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

> Refresh tokens expire only when one of the following occurs: - The user is deleted

In theory, it should work. Why it is not? And how to fix it, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication uses ID tokens that are valid for one hour. Until the user's existing token expires, they can continue to use that token to access resources. But they won't be able to get a new ID token, so it will take no longer than an hour before they lose full access.

If this is not good enough for your scenario, you'll want to take additional measures to protect the files.

For data in the database, the documentation shows how to [detect ID token revocation in security rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation_in_database_rules). But this approach won't work for Cloud Storage, as you can't perform a lookup of the revoked tokens in there.

For Cloud Storage you could implement your own API to control access to the files, where you'd then perform the same lookup of revoked tokens. That's the only way I can think of to implement immediate revocation.

Comment: I would need to change the entire infrastructure with this approach which I don't want to do. We are using storage/firestore directly from Ftonrend and have no additional layer of API, where safety is provided by security rules.

Comment: ID tokens are valid for an hour, and there is no way to invalidate such a bearer token once it's been created. The approach outlined in my answer is really the only way to block the user from accessing resources with their existing token. The link I provided precisely how to detect this in security rules, so that sounds like your best option.

Comment: I am just pulling on the frontend side new token every 15 seconds. With that, I have much more smaller window, in comparison to 1h, to give users better UX. Later on I would like to add WebSockets which will let me know when User Claims are changes to retrieve new token on FE.  It will prevent some unwanted spamming. Still, it does not solve issues when somebody steal you a token but it is significant solution for my defined problem.